# Are the units of a monoid-graded ring homogeneous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, graded-rings

I'm just trying to find a reference for the following statement: if $R$ is an $M$-graded integral domain, where $M$ is a monoid, then every unit of $R$ is homogeneous.

[This source](https://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf) (in particular, Exercise 1.1) says that the statement is true when $M$ is the group of integers $\mathbb Z$, but I cannot seem to find a source for the more general statement.

Is there a source or simple proof for this proposition?

Comment: Notice it's important that the ring be a domain. It's false if there are zero divisors.

Comment: @MattSamuel yeah, let me edit the question -- I forgot to specify that $R$ is a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.  For instance, notice that $R=\mathbb{C}$ can be $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded by saying that $R_0=\mathbb{R}$ and $R_1=\mathbb{R}i$.  But not every unit is homogeneous, since this ring is in fact a field!

More generally, if $K$ is a field and $L$ is an extension of $K$ generated by an element $\alpha$ whose minimal polynomial has the form $x^d-a$, then $L$ has a $\mathbb{Z}/d$-grading whose $n$th graded piece is $K\alpha^n$.